# Win32Exception: The network path was not found

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, amazon-aws, .net-core

Estou recebendo o seguinte erro em minha aplicação que está hospedada no aws

> SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
>
> InvalidOperationException: An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure. Consider enabling transient error resiliency by adding 'EnableRetryOnFailure()' to the 'UseSqlServer' call.

Esse erro aparentemente é por causa da instancia do banco, mas o mais estranho é que pelo SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT eu consigo usar o banco corretamente, e apenas na aplicação web que está dando esse erro, sabem oque posso fazer ?

A Aplicação está no Elastic Beanstalk e o banco no RDS no aws

Minha Conexão:

"Data Source=mydbdevkonbaseinstance.codi6jnwlp6k.sa-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com,1433;Initial Catalog=********;Integrated Security=False;User ID=*********;Password=***********;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"

Comment: O banco está no mesmo servidor da aplicação? Como está a string de conexão? Dê mais detalhes...

Comment: @LINQ vou colocar na pergunta

Comment: Por favor especifique na pergunta quais são suas Subnets (Sub-redes) e Security groups (Grupos de segurança).  Como solução temporária você pode adicionar o endereço IP do ElaticBeanstalk EC2 no Security group do RDS.
Mais detalhes na documentação em português da AWS sobre conectar umas instância Beanstalk com RDS: 

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.RDS.html#rds-external-defaultvpc 

Aqui como codificar em c# para acessar uma instancia RDS:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_NET.rds.html#dotnet-rds-connect